# regist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

Tags: python, django

i got a error that
TypeError at /accounts/regist/
regist() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'   .
i can understand there is no variable in my file.
but,in login,no template_name file can be worked.
So,i cannot know how to fix it.

I wrote in urls.py of accounts,

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/regist.html'},
        name='regist' ),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
]
```

in views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import RegisterForm



def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('main:index')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)
```

if i have to define template_name,which file should i write it and how?
Are there differences to make system login page and regist page?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to specify a `template_name` when you are using your own function-based view, so just remove the `{'template_name': 'registration/accounts/regist.html'}` bit from the registration URL.